# VBA POWERPOINT: Copy text with formatting from powerpoint to word

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

Right now I'm copying text into word like so:

```
wrdDoc.Range.InsertAfter someShapeWithText.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCr & vbCr
```

I want it to copy with formatting i.e. certain words are bolded, coloured, etc.
Cant quite figure out how to do it. Fairly new to VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger `copy` and `paste` to keep formatting. I think you could go this way (using your variables which I couldn't test)

```
someShapeWithText.TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
wrdDoc.Range.Paste
```